# Problem with IF validating XPATH in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium, xpath

Im trying to scrape one ASPX form, and i`m having difficulties on make one IF for select different types os results, i have blank results first and data results second.

How do i make one IF to validate one XPATH? IF the XPATH is true i wanna do one thing, ELSE i wanna do another thing.

That`s my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Python37\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(".aspx")

planilha = openpyxl.load_workbook('BASE 05-09.xlsx')

sheet = planilha['Aba1']

for Count in range(2,5552):

    box_cpf = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TxtCpf']")
    box_cpf.send_keys(sheet.cell(row=Count, column=5).value)

    pesquisar_bto = driver.find_elements_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btPesquisar")[0]
    pesquisar_bto.click()

    if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div"):
        resultado_pesquisa = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div")
        sheet.cell(row=Count, column=6).value = resultado_pesquisa.text
    else:
        resultado_pesquisa = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
        sheet.cell(row=Count, column=6).value = resultado_pesquisa.text

    planilha.save("BASE 05-09.xlsx")
    time.sleep(.5)

    limpar_bto = driver.find_elements_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btLimpar")[0]
    limpar_bto.click()
    time.sleep(.5)

driver.quit()
```

That`s the XPATH when i have empty result:

```
"/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div"
```

And the XPATH when i have results:

```
"/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"
```

Sorry if im asking something to obvious, im new in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below enter wait for rows, check if there's empty result and get the value.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Python37\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

sheet = planilha['Aba1']
driver.get(".aspx")

for Count in range(2, 5552):
    driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TxtCpf").send_keys(sheet.cell(row=Count, column=5).value, Keys.RETURN)

    results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[id*='DXMainTable'] > tbody > tr[class*=DataRow]")))
    resultado_pesquisa = results[0].text.strip() if "EmptyDataRow" in results[0].get_attribute("class") else results[0].find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text.strip()

    sheet.cell(row=Count, column=6).value = resultado_pesquisa
    planilha.save("BASE 05-09.xlsx")
    time.sleep(.5)

    driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btLimpar").click()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: when i try this code i get an error: 'NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./td[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)'

Answer (score 0):

When you say " IF the XPATH is true ", I assume you mean if the XPath successfully finds an element on the page. You can use ExpectedConditions in a `try` / `except` block against `TimeoutException` to accomplish this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# attempt to find element using first XPath
try: 
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "YourXPathHere")))
except TimeoutException:
    # XPath element did not exist. Do something else here.

# If you end up here, your XPath returned a WebElement successfully.
print(element)
```

This code attempts to wait for the element specified by XPath in `YourXPathHere`.This is performed in `try` / `except` block to catch the `TimeoutException` encountered if the element does NOT exist on page. You can handle that case in the `except`. If you pass over the `except`, meaning XPath found element on page, your code will end up at the last line in sample.

Comment: When i try ur code i get this error: 

File "<ipython-input-30-840f845b9790>", line 28
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div))

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Your XPath needs a closing quotation mark at the end "